# Give color to the text of HTML table email body based on disk usage condition using Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, email, tabulate

I am sending out an html table in an email body using python. The html table consists of disk usage and I need to convert the text color in red when disk usage is above 80 percent . I have tried so far [Give color to the text of HTML table body based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548045/give-color-to-the-text-of-html-table-body-based-on-condition). However, this uses excel and does not add the borders which in my case i want to keep.

This is the code I'm using that works to get the email without colouring the text:

```html
me = 'noreply@automationtest.com'

server = 'some smtp server'
you = ‘email@someautomation.com'

text = """
{table}
"""

html = """
<html>
<head>
<style> 
  table, th, td {{ border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }}
  th, td {{ padding: 5px; }}
</style>
</head>
<body><p style="font-family:verdana">Hi,</p>
<p style="font-family:verdana">sometext</p>
{table}
<p style="font-family:verdana">sometext</p>
<p style="font-family:verdana">Regards</p>
<p style="font-family:verdana">someme</p>
</body></html>
""" 

with open('files/file.csv') as input_file:
    reader = DictReader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)
    for row in data:
      row['Usage in %'] = pd.to_numeric(row['Usage in %'])
      if row['Usage in %'] >= 80:
      row['Usage in %'] = "<p style='color:red'>%s</p>"%row['Usage in %']


text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))

html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="unsafehtml"))
message = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])
print(html)


message['From'] = me
message['To'] = you
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(me, password)
server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
server.quit()
```

This is the output I get in the email
[image]
Expected output
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop through your data after reading it from the csv and change the value of disk usage to `<p style='color:red'>Value</p>` if its greater than 80

Then in tabulate change the `tablefmt` argument to `"unsafehtml"`.

This should output html that incorporates your own styles.

The code below outputs "moon" in red color to give you a proof of concept:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
table = [["Sun",696000,1989100000],["Earth",6371,5973.6],
         ["<p style='color:red'>Moon</p>",1737,73.5], 
         ["Mars",3390,641.85]]
print(tabulate(table, tablefmt='unsafehtml'))
```

Comment: Hi @machazthegamer, thanks for your reply. I did as you suggested and it looks like it's working as expected. However, I'm not getting the header anymore. It's excluding it. I will update the post. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I updated the post by adding the loop. I'm getting the text in red. The part that is being excluded is the first row(server, Total size GB, Total data, and usage in %). It adds as header the second row instead (Row A).

Comment: It's worth to mention that I also changed reader = csv.reader(input_file) to reader = DictReader(input_file) since I get the following error when using csv.reader(input_file):   row['Usage in %'] = int(row['Usage in %']) TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: post a different question with the current problem, this is getting confusing.@chiko